# How to use asterisk (*) in saltstack pillar function declaration in top.sls file?

Tags: automation, salt-stack

I am new to saltstack automation and was wondering if there is a way to use asterisk (*) in saltstack pillar function declaration. Let me explain you all the details.

My pillar root for prod environment is

```
======
# grep -i pillar_root -A3 /etc/salt/master 
pillar_roots:
  prod:
    - /srv/pillar
======
```

I have top.sls file in /srv/pillar directory and the content of the file is given below.

```
======
# cat /srv/pillar/top.sls
prod:
  '*':
    - user.avatar_user
    - user.avatar_sudo_user
======
```

I will be adding *.sls files in /srv/pillar/user/ directory. However, please let me know if there is a way like this

```
======
prod:
  '*':
    - user.*
======
```

Thus, I won't need to add corresponding sls entries in top.sls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the syntax you're wanting.

You could use jinja to shell out and list any files in that directory. That would probably look something like this:
Contents of `/srv/pillar/top.sls`:

```
{% user_pillars = salt['cmd.run']('ls /srv/pillar/user*').split() %}

prod:
  '*':
{% for dir in user_pillars %}
    - {{ dir }}
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't tested this exact code, but it should be close to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a user/init.sls file, which explicitly includes the rest of the user files in its directory.  Then all you would need to do in the top.sls file is include:

```
prod:
  '*':
    - user
```